I installed tch in rust and it doesn't work
I created a simple rust project and imported tch, and it doesn't work, even if the program doesn't use it.
use tch::nn;
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

Although the program compiles, running it produces an error:
The procedure entry point __kmpc_masked could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\libtorch
\torch_cpu.dll
I tried reinstalling cuda to fit the torch version (12.4) I tried playing with the dependencies. The current toml file has the following:
[package]
name = "tch_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
tch = {version="0.17.0", path="tch-rs"}

[dev-dependencies]
torch-sys = {version="0.17.0", path="tch-rs/torch-sys"}

However, I also tried just using the dependencies when I installed tch using cargo add (changing the tch to just tch="0.17.0" and that didn't work either.
I tried setting my environment variables, as was shown in the github page, and even tried to add the LIBTORCH_USE_PYTORCH variable as pytorch does work on python on my machine.
I am using a windows 10 machine with an RTX4060. Help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank You!
Few Clarifications: Firstly, when I say that "it didn't work" I mean that the exact same result happened as specified above i.e. The program compiles but running it gives the message above. To be clear: This is a runtime issue not a compile time issue.
Additionaly, I want to clarify that the error above happens when I run the exe manually. When I run it from cmd, it displays the following error instead: process didn't exit successfully: target\debug\tch_test.exe (exit code: 0xc0000139, STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND)
Secondly, this is a minimal reproducible example. This was a new project I created from scratch to try to fix this issue. It is just a new project with the tch imported as specified (I tried 2 ways, via cargo add, and via cloning the github repo). There are no extra files beyond that, just the cloned tch-rs, gitignore, lock files that come by default, and the toml file above (which I also tried the default and it didn't work), nothing else.
I tried following the guidelines on the github page https://github.com/LaurentMazare/tch-rs and this tutorial https://www.swiftdiaries.com/rust/pytorch/ none worked. I even tried to run the example files in the tch-rs I cloned (without doing any modification to the folder) and it produced the same result.

Why are you overriding path of those dependencies? Please share your project structure. What is full compiler error when you run cargo check?

I ran cargo check and it returned no errors. The project has an src folder with a main.rs file with the code above. The tch-rs package which I cloned from github.(though I also installed tch using cargo add) and then the lock and toml file. Note that as I said in the question, I've tried to not override the dependencies and it still didn't work.

"it still didn't work" is not enough information to debug this problem. Please edit your question and include detailed description of your project layout, and full compiler error message. If you don't know how to produce minimal reproducible example for Rust, please read tag wiki.

I added clarifications

I figured out the solution! I had the wrong version of torch installed (2.4.1 instead of 2.4.0)
Unfortunately, the website doesn't let you download past versions of libtorch, unless you manually edit the url to the correct version.
